# Cannot spawn application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, passenger, ruby-1.9.3

I have rvm, passenger, ruby 1.9.3, nginx but I now get this error

> > Cannot spawn application '/path/to/my/app': Could not read from the spawn server: Connection reset by peer (104)

I have `passenger_root` set to the output of `passenger-config --root` and `ruby-1.9.3-p125` for `passenger_ruby`

I did have to do `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` because passenger kept trying to install with 1.8.7 support rather than 1.9.3

i've even set spawn mode to conservative.

Is there anything I'm missing out?

Comment: please provide more details, apache - passenger config, `rvm info`

Comment: i've made too many changes since. but i've moved to nginx+unicorn and it's much easier to set up.

Comment: I am also having this issue, but only when I set `passenger_user_switching off;` in my webserver config file.

Comment: your app can't start -- try to start your app manually and see if it will start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening most likely because your passenger user does not have permissions to run your application or your application itself is not starting up properly.