# Troubles running Rails on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I've tried everything I know and looked up and down on stack and google.

I'm using raspbian with apache2/passenger4.0.37  Ruby 2.1.0 Rails 4.0.2.

When I try to load my site I get a 500 error and when I check apache logs I have

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- /phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger.rb:233:in `require_passenger_lib'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:68:in `libext'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:81:in `library_name'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:214:in `compile_and_load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:49:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:376:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
        from /usr/share/phusion-passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:79:in `<main>'
[ pid=8453 thr=3069558784 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:862 time=2014-02-14 19:47:12.154 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/var/www/gobles': Could not read from the spawn server: Connection reset by peer (104)
  Backtrace:
     in 'virtual Passenger::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Client.h:742)
     in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:294)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:563)
```

There are no log files in the ruby application.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks :D

Since we're on the path of permissions errors just figured I'd share.

```
ps aux | grep -i apache
```

Yields

```
root      9457  0.0  1.7  36584  7984 ?        Ss   11:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9493  0.0  1.2  36836  5696 ?        S    11:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9494  0.0  1.0  36616  4528 ?        S    11:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9495  0.0  1.2  36836  5696 ?        S    11:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9496  0.0  1.0  36616  4512 ?        S    11:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9497  0.0  1.0  36616  4512 ?        S    11:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9499  0.0  1.0  36616  4512 ?        S    11:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

and for passenger

```
root      9460  0.0  0.3   4420  1712 ?        Ssl  11:13   0:00 PassengerWatchdog
root      9467  0.0  0.5  13376  2272 ?        Sl   11:13   0:00 PassengerHelperAgent
nobody    9478  0.0  0.7  11060  3212 ?        Sl   11:13   0:00 PassengerLoggingAgent
```

and a glance at my app

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Feb 14 18:30 app
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 14 18:30 bin
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb 14 18:30 config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  154 Feb 14 18:30 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 14 18:30 db
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1187 Feb 14 18:51 Gemfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2844 Feb 14 18:52 Gemfile.lock
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1187 Feb 14 22:59 Gemfile.save
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 14 18:30 lib
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 14 19:42 log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 14 18:30 public
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  251 Feb 14 18:30 Rakefile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  478 Feb 14 18:30 README.rdoc
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Feb 14 18:30 test
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 14 18:30 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 14 18:30 vendor
```

I've tried chown www-data:www-data    No luck there either.

Comment: This question may provide useful info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894939/cannot-spawn-application

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that based on this question [Cannot spawn application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894939/cannot-spawn-application), the problem is that the passenger user does not have permission to run the rails application.

You can tell by looking at the log file

```
Cannot spawn application '/var/www/gobles': Could not read from the spawn server: Connection reset by peer (104).
```

One thing you could try doing, is finding out what the passenger username is, and then do a `chmod -R` on the `/var/www/gobles` directory.

Comment: Read through your link, and tried chmod -R 755 on the application directory.  Still getting the same errors.  I also tried [link](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_the_apache_error_log_says_that_the_spawn_manager_script_does_not_exist_or_that_it_does_not_have_permission_to_execute_it)  but that didn't seem to work I kept getting "can't apply partial context to unlabeled file"  I did some searching on that, but all the other suggestions didn't seem to work either.

Comment: What are you looking for.  I'm not that good in linux.  The above is still the error I'm getting.  /var/log/messages has nothing in it. and /var/www/gobles/log as nothing either.